# Can i select certain special characters that is not allowed in the textbox?

Tags: javascript, html

I don't want to allowed only the special character like < > and &
And here's the code that i search on the internet but this code did not accept all of the special character.

```js
var specialKeys = new Array();
specialKeys.push(8); //Backspace
specialKeys.push(9); //Tab
specialKeys.push(46); //Delete
specialKeys.push(36); //Home
specialKeys.push(35); //End
specialKeys.push(37); //Left
specialKeys.push(39); //Right
function IsAlphaNumeric(e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode == 1 ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
  var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90) || (keyCode >= 97 && keyCode <= 122) || (specialKeys.indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1 && e.charCode != e.keyCode));
  document.getElementById("error").style.display = ret ? "none" : "inline";
  return ret;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 9pt;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<body>
  Alphanumeric value:
  <input type="text" id="text1" onkeypress="return IsAlphaNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" />
  <span id="error" style="color: Red; display: none">* Special Characters not allowed</span>
</body>

</html>
```

is there a way to add keycode for the special characters like . , ; : ! ? - ( ) = +

Comment: Seems like you try to escape your input text with JavaScript. Make sure to do this validation also on the back-end side. Furthermore, you will be able to paste text containing those characters into your text field with your approach. You could just replace every character, which is not allowed, when the textfield value changed.

Comment: ok thanks for the information. i'll be working that right now.